# How to fetch the immediate next value after a condition becomes true?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a text file contain values as :

```
  ABC        BGT          ADAD          ADA
1035.08     2424.45     42444.43    31314.242
1035.18     3434.43     2424.353    2424.355
1067.45     123.454     123.545     1213.45
1067.60     2323.32     1223.231    2323.343
1068.00    2313.45     3433.233    1313.343
1068.56    3232.35     2424.424    4224.344
1069.45    3244.34     2332.344    2323.343
----------  ----        ---         -----
1093.32    212.343     2313.232     1213.24
1093.60    5665.65     6789.760     88343
```

I have an array `ab=[1035.15,1067.86,1093.58]`

I am going to check each value in the array ab in text file . For example, If I take first value 1035.15 and check in text file I got lines

```
    1035.08     2424.45     42444.43    31314.242
    1035.18     3434.43     2424.353    2424.355
```

But I want

```
    1035.18     3434.43     2424.353    2424.355
```

If the value in the array is greater ,the immediate next value should fetch.

If I take second value `1067.86`, then line should be

```
    1068.00    2313.45     3433.233    1313.343
```

Hot to get so?

What I have done:

`r_out` is an array which stores filenames.

```
for i in range(len(r_out)):
    f4=open(r_out[i],'r')
    for line in f4.readlines():
        string=line
        num=ab[i].split('.')[0]
        dec=ab[i].split('.')[1]

        if re.search(r'\b'+num,string.split()[0]):

            value=string.split()[0].split('.')[1]
            if int(dec)>int(value):
                string.next()
```

Comment: start by properly converting your data into list of rows of floats: `data = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f4]` and work with numeric values instead of strings.

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre.Ok But how can I get the next closest values

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off [@Jean-FrançoisFabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704032/how-to-fetch-the-immediate-next-value-after-a-condition-becomes-true#comment101851055_57704032):

```
data = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f4]
```

The above will give you all the lines in your file as a matrix.

Now to find the line that is *closest* to your value, you can use the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function like so:

```
search_for = 1035.15
closest_line = min(data, key=lambda line: abs(line[0] - search_for))
```

Now `closest_line` will contain the line whose value is closest to your search term.

```
>>> min(data, key=lambda line: abs(line[0] - 1035.15))
[1035.18, 3434.43, 2424.353, 2424.355]
>>> min(data, key=lambda line: abs(line[0] - 1067.86))
[1068.0, 2313.45, 3433.233, 1313.343]
>>> min(data, key=lambda line: abs(line[0] - 1093.58))
[1093.6, 5665.65, 6789.76, 88343.0]
```

Comment: But these values [1035.15,1067.86,1093.58] are stored in an array. How can I implement this using arrays?

Comment: @itsbinz use a loop

Comment: An error occurs on printing data.String cant convert to float. I have recently updated the txt file contents.How to solve the error now?

Comment: @itsbinz my suggestion to you would be to either read the file with a CSV reader (Python has one) or remove all those non numeric characters before attempting to convert all the values to float. I'm not at a computer now to help you

Comment: `line.strip().split()` you don't need `strip` as `split` drops consecutive blank chars: no risk of empty cells.

Comment: @itsbinz please ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, you can apply "searchsorted":

```
import pandas as pd

for fn in r_out:
    df=pd.read_csv(fn, sep=r"\s+",engine="python")
    df=df.sort_values("ABC",ascending=True) # it has to be sorted, if it weren't already
    rows=df["ABC"].searchsorted(ab,side="left")
    print( df.loc[rows] )
```